# Unable to read a GZIP file from AWS s3 bucket in pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho-spoon

My requirement is to read a gzip file from s3 bucket in pentaho. I am able to do it with virtual file system in this way

**s3://aCcEsSkEy:SecrEttAccceESSKeeey@s3/your-s3-bucket/your_file.gzip**, but the issue is my secret has a (slash in between) so I am unable to read the file from that particular bucket and the path.

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: have you tried url-encoding the slash? maybe using \\ instead of a single

Comment: i actually have + and / in between the charcters... i tried putting the double slash but it did not work